# Ada: loop is causing later code to be unreachable

Tags: ada

I'm new to Ada. I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```vhdl
begin
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Student ID Score");
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("===================");
readAnswers(pAnswers, 1);

loop
declare
   counter : Integer := 0;
   studentInput : String := Get_Line(Input);
   studentScore : Integer;
begin
   numOfTests := numOfTests + 1;
   current_student.ID := GetID(studentInput);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put(Ada.Strings.Unbounded.To_String(current_student.ID));
   readAnswers(studentInput (6 .. studentInput'Last) ,0);
   studentScore := scoreTest(current_student.student_answer, current_answer_key, number_of_questions);
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(studentScore);
      New_Line(1);
end;
end loop;

Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("===================");
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Tests Graded = ");
Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(numOfTests);
end;
```

Unfortunately, GNAT tells me that all the code after the loop is unreachable. How can I get this program to execute the loop and the code after it?

Comment: You are in an infinite loop, that is why later code is unreachable. Therefore, you need a break condition telling the loop when to stop.

Answer (score 12):

You forget the exit condition :

```
loop
  exit when condition;
end loop;
```

Comment: @Conner; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

There si no condition on when the loop should be finished so it runs indefenetly so the code after it is never reached.